# Is there a way to move a wxNotebook page to a separate window?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, mdi

I am planning a C++ wxWidgets GUI and I want the user to be able to pull a page from a notebook (that makes up most of the main window) and turn it into its own separate second window. The idea is that in a single-screen setup, you would have the main window maximized and switch between the two pages within the main window, while in a dual-screen setup (or if you are okay with smaller windows) you could pop out one of the pages and move it to the second screen (or have the two windows side by side).

I know of the wxAuiNotebook class, but according to the documentation, it does not offer exactly that functionality: You can only move a page to some other tabbed container, but not to a new window. Conversely, using wxAui, you can undock a window but you cannot add it to a notebook.

So my current idea is to include a small button on each notebook page that creates an entirely new window exactly like the current notebook page and deletes the page from the notebook (and vice-versa in the new window). But this seems messy because it would include destroying a perfectly valid object only to recreate the exact same thing in a slightly different way.

Does anyone have any advice on how to make this happen in an elegant way?

Comment: I suggest for you to build the auidemo program provided with the library and try it. Maybe it is possible to do what you want. Just build the sample and play with it.

Comment: I did, but it does not offer what I need out of the box. That's why I am trying to get input on how to implement something to that effect efficiently myself.